# Ansible: How to use "and" and "or" conditions in when clause for

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

The following task should be executed if 3 AND conditions in when clause are meet. One of the AND conditions has an OR conditional inside. There is an error while evaluating OR clause. Could you please inform why the OR conditional is not working?

```
***- name: "invoke playbook for control tables update"
  include_tasks: sdp_purge_control_tbl.yml
  when:
    - job_exec_state.stdout.find('OK') == -1
    - data_in_main_a.stdout.find('created')!= -1
    - (rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1 or rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1)
  ignore_errors: True***
```

ERROR CODE:

```
***
fatal: [sdp-test1a]: FAILED! => {}
MSG:
The conditional check 'rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1 or rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1 or rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'
The error appears to be in '/home/devops/ansible/roles/sdp/tasks/sdp_purge_scenario1.yml': line 125, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
    - name: "invoke playbook for control tables update"
      ^ here
...ignoring***
```

Conditions that work ok:

```
job_exec_state.stdout.find('OK') == -1 
data_in_main_a.stdout.find('created')!= -1
```

Condition that fails:

```
(rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1 or rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1)
```

If rename_syn_result_chk_b contains 'successfully' task runs ok because it is before the OR conditional, but if rename_syn_result_chk_b does not contain the string and then rename_syn_result_chk_a contains 'successfully', task still fails.

I have tried with  and without parenthesis but no luck. OR clause alternatives attempted:

```
(rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1) or (rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1)

rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1 or rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1

(rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1 or rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1)
```

Code to understand the variables... it is basically an output of a grep from a file that is later used to find "successfully" string.

```
   - name: "check rename to synonym A"
      shell: |
        grep '{{ item.synA_name }}' `ls {{sql_log_dir}}/Rename_Hist2Syn*|tail -1`
      register: rename_syn_result_chk_a

    - name: "check rename to synonym B"
      shell: |
        grep  '{{ item.synB_name }}' `ls {{sql_log_dir}}/Rename_Hist2Syn*|tail -1`
      register: rename_syn_result_chk_b
```

Answer (score 0):

`or` works between booleans, it does not provide a fallback in case of error, which is your situation: `'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'`, which means that `rename_syn_result_chk_b` or `rename_syn_result_chk_a` does not have a `stdout`. 
It's quite odd this happens as it looks like your not ignoring errors in the tasks generating those variables.

You need to be protective in that case with a `default` filter for example:

```yaml
    - (rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout | default).find('successfully') != -1 or (rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout | default).find('successfully') != -1
```

It can also be simplified into:

```yaml
    - 'successfully' in rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout | default or 'successfully' in rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout | default
```

Comment: Thanks Zigarn, I came to know about "is defined" and "default" clauses, I modified the task as below and it is working now I used "is defined".     It was failing because if stdout was not found, the error caused the playbook not to check after OR clause.          
        - (rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout is defined and (rename_syn_result_chk_b.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1)) or (rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout is defined and (rename_syn_result_chk_a.stdout.find('successfully')!= -1))
      ignore_errors: True